# Allow passwordless 'peer' auth where matches, but require password for other users

Tags: postgresql

I have what I think is a simple Postgres authentication requirement, but I can't figure out the `pg_hba.conf` incantation to make it work.

I have a database user (role) named `dbuser` which is the owner of a password-protected database `adb`. There is a corresponding Unix user named `dbuser`. The Unix user `dbuser` should be able to connect to `adb` without a password, all other Unix users should be able to connect by using the `dbuser` role and providing the database password. I.e.

```
sudo -u dbuser psql -U dbuser adb
```

should not require a database password, but

```
sudo -u any_other_user psql -U dbuser adb
```

should require the database password.

The `pg_hba.conf` entry:

```
local adb dbuser peer
```

works for the first case, but fails for the second (psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "dbuser"). I understand why, but can't figure out the right rules to do what I want. Unix socket connections (local) only. Postgres 9.2 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want isn't possible with PostgreSQL's current authentication scheme. When `peer` authentication fails, PostgreSQL won't fall through to the next entry in `pg_hba.conf`. Only the first entry is used, and if it fails, the connection is rejected. The `peer` mode does not offer the option of falling back to password authentication if the user ID doesn't match.

So you can't do it. Sorry. The closest you can come is using `local` (unix socket) connections with `peer` auth and requiring other clients to connect over TCP/IP (`host`) sockets with `md5` auth. Using a different protocol lets you pick a different auth method for each.

I recently proposed a change to authentication behaviour on pgsql-hackers that might permit what you want in a later version, if I can convince people it's a good idea. Basically, the `peer` mode would take an `md5_fallback` option that'd allow it to request a password from the client if it failed `peer` authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have been using a combination of local and host, it just seemed ugly and I was looking for a cleaner solution. I like the idea of md5_fallback, that would seem to cover a lot of currently impossible use cases.